# Spreading props to a list of Components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to send a bunch of props to a Component.

In console.logs I noted that everything is working as I expected, every object has its correct value, every spread operation is working. But my Cards doesn't show in the page.
Is this way correct?

```
        return ( 
            <div>
                {this.state.articles.forEach((card) => {
                    <ArticleCard {...card} />
                })}
            </div>
        )
```

[Image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Iy2.png)

Comment: Are you sure this.state.articles has data? And how your articlecard component looks like?

Comment: ArticleCard is a component using a lot of props to build something like [this](https://codepen.io/andytran/pen/BNjymy/image/large.png) and yep, this.states.articles was filled. Click in the image link on the question, or [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Iy2.png), you'll see... thanks for trying to help ^^, but some guys already solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.forEach` does not return anything. You need to use `Array.map`. Also you should be returning the component to be rendered in the callback.

```
return ( 
  <div>
      {this.state.articles.map((card) => (
          <ArticleCard {...card} />
      )}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using forEach, you should use `map` function on array, and with `return` keyword to return each and every `ArticleCard`

```js
return( 
<div>
  {this.state.articles.map((card) => {
    return <ArticleCard {...card} />
  })}
</div>
)
```